# printing pairs of a list in SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog

basically, I want to print pairs from one list like this

```
?- [1 2 3 4 5,R]
```

the output is

```
R = [1, 2] 
R = [1, 3] 
R = [1, 4] 
R = [1, 5] 
R = [2, 3] 
R = [2, 4] 
R = [2, 5] 
R = [3, 4] 
R = [3, 5] 
R = [4, 5]
```

I used the code that creates subsets and modified it

```
sub(0,_,[]).
sub(N,[X|T],[X|R]):-N>0,N1 is N-1,sub(N1,T,R).
sub(N,[_|T],R):-N>0,sub(N,T,R).
```

and I would call 
    sub(2,[1,2,3,4,5],R)

but is there a way to do it without using a counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog is about defining relations (in the form of rules) and to try to avoid thinking procedurally (steps of execution to achieve a result). You can solve this by breaking it down into simple rules for the pairs:

1. For a list with head `H` and tail `T`, a valid pair is `[H,E]` where `E` is a member of `T`.
2. For a list with head `H` and tail `T`, a valid pair is a pair taken from `T`.

If you think about these rules, they are (1) mutually exclusive (there isn't a solution that matches both rules), and (2) they are complete (they cover all of the valid solutions).

Writing these in Prolog, you get:

```
pair([H|T], [H,E]) :- member(E, T).
pair([_|T], P) :- pair(T, P).
```

This provides a relational solution which yields:

```
| ?- sub([a,b,c,d], S).

S = [a,b] ? ;

S = [a,c] ? ;

S = [a,d] ? ;

S = [b,c] ? ;

S = [b,d] ? ;

S = [c,d] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

And works in a more general case:

```
| ?- pair(L, P).

L = [A,B]
P = [A,B] ? ;

L = [A,B|_]
P = [A,B] ? ;

L = [A,_,B|_]
P = [A,B] ? ;

L = [A,_,_,B|_]
P = [A,B] ? ;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

an easy way:

```
?- L = [1,2,3,4,5], forall((nth1(I,L,X), nth1(J,L,Y), I<J), writeln(I/J)).
1/2
1/3
1/4
1/5
2/3
2/4
2/5
3/4
3/5
4/5
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, since you don't have to account for subsets of arbitrary length.

There are two steps you need to account for, and both have two variants.

1. Select the first element of the pair:

   1. Use the head of the list
   2. Discard the head and pick it out of the tail of the list
2. Select the second element of the pair:

   1. Use the head of the list
   2. Discard the head and pick it out of the tail of the list

---

```
% Use the head as the first element
pairs((H, P2), [H | T]) :- pairs((H, P2), T).

% If we have the first element, use the head as the second element
pairs((P1, H), [H | _]) :- nonvar(P1).

% Ignore the head and pick what we need out of the tail
pairs(P, [_ | T]) :- pairs(P, T).
```

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with the head?